# Did Ash meet Goh before he meets Serena?

Tags: pokemon

In the anime, does young Ash meet Goh before or after he met Serena?

Similar to how *Pokémon XYZ* showed Ash's childhood, the first episode of *Pokémon Journeys* also shows Ash's childhood, but it also shows Goh's childhood.

Did Ash meet Goh before he met Serena?

Comment: Im only asking because Pokemon Journeys seems to contradict XYZ as to Ashs Childhood

Answer (score -2):

### Ash meets Serena first even though as kids Goh was part of  professor Oak's pokemon summer school.

Goh was the type of person who was only friends with Chloe and similar to Iris from Pokemon; they couldn't make friends with other people but Ash meets Goh when riding on lugia in Pokemon Journeys.

In XYZ when Serena asks Ash if he remembers her he says he doesn't and at that age he was even more focused on Pokemon then he is now and didn't even notice the people around him until he met Misty and Brock then subsequently his other companions.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold assertions?